# Sign in with apple - revoke auth

Tags: ios, authentication, token

https://appleid.apple.com/auth/revoke This api for revoking auth from the apple account and getting 200 OK response but still not able unlink apps from apple so do we need to call token api for an access token? If yes here is the screenshot.

API for token generating
[AuthToken API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGGgZ.png) getting invalid_request so how can we unlink apps from the apple setting account?

Comment: There is probably something wrong with your code, when you have submitted the request correctly it will remove it from settings, 200 is a common thing and sadly it doesn't mean that the action was successful

Comment: Ya !!! actually, JWT was wrong which I created but finally, I got the solution & I am able to unlink apps successfully thanks for your response.

Comment: Hi @harshshah, did you managed to get call successfully for  auth/token and auth/revoke?

Comment: Yes, I did this to get a successful call.

Comment: @harshshah can you guide me as I am facing issue to get manage success in https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token. I am getting invalid client response. for client_id i have set app bundle id, and grant_type =  "authorization_code" and for client secret i have set the key in .p8 file downloaded form iTunes connect for sign in with apple for my app. Is there any thing i am missing? or are the values i set correct. I guess my client_secret is not correct. Can you help me as you have managed to achieve it..

Comment: Yes, You can try to create a client create using this method

const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(`Path_P8_file`, 'utf8')
    return JWT.sign({ 
      iss: Constant.APPLE_DATA.TEAM_ID,
      iat: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
      exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 360000,
      aud: process.env.APPLE_AUD,
      sub: process.env.APPLE_BUNDLE_ID
    }, 
    privateKey, 
    { 
        algorithm: 'ES256',
        header: {
            alg: 'ES256',
            kid: process.env.KEY_ID
        } 
    });